# Is there a way to tell browsers that a field is NOT the username?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, autocomplete

This is an old bug (which the browser designers, in their 1984-style wisdom, have decided to call a "feature", because up is down, peace is war, and the computer always knows better than the user), but it just bit me in the posterior, and there is so much contradictory information out there (including all the previous questions on StackOverflow) that I don't know where to turn.

I have a form with a password field at the end, serving as a signature of sorts. The form does not have a username field, nor anything even remotely like a username field. What it does have is an `input type="text"` which is intended to contain an ICD10 code. (Size is 5 and maxlength is 6, so it's much too small for a username.)

Between that last text field and the password field, there's a textarea, 10 times 4 sets of radio buttons, and another textarea, so no matter how insane your semantics are, there is simply no logical way to conclude that the text field should be overwritten with a username, yet that is manifestly what happens: the browser asks whether it should remember the password, you tell it "yes", and the next time you open a similar form, the last diagnosis code has been clobbered with what the browser, in its wisdom, has decided must be your username, all indications to the contrary notwithstanding. (Chances are, it's another diagnosis code, just not the correct one.)

The kicker here is, it would be perfectly fine for the browser to remember the password. I have no issue with the browser remembering the password. So `autofill="newpassword"` (if that's still even a thing) isn't what I want. What I *do* have issue with is the browser deciding that a random text field must be the username.

For Internet Explorer, adding a text field before the password field and hiding it with `display:none` works around the bug. But Chrome really, really insists it knows better than you do, and the undisplayed text field does bupkis. Ditto for Firefox. So instead, I did `position:absolute;margin-left:-1000em;` and that seems to do the trick on Chrome and Firefox. For now. If you cross your fingers and pray to the right gods. I have no idea what, if anything, works on Safari.

**Is there an actual setting I can add to my form that would prevent this bug?** As in, not a kludgy workaround, but an actual standards-compliant setting? Something I can put on the diagnosis field saying "this is not a username field"? Failing that, is there an accepted **current** workaround to this error? One that works *in 2017* on all the major browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge), preferably without breaking accessibility? Or do people just use the `margin-left:-1000em;` kludge, ugly though it is?

(If the kludge is the only way open right now, do we know whether it's likely to continue working, or are the evil browser designers even now plotting how to yank the rug from under us?)

Comment: remove the autocomplete attributes from the fields you do not want to be over-written... If you have a third-party form filler addon disable it. Test your login forms with autocomplete turned on and off. Include reproduction mashups (jsfiddles) with your questions.

Comment: @RobParsons: what autocomplete attributes? And what on God's green earth does my login form have to do with any of this?

Comment: Also, it's rather impossible to provide a jsfiddle of something that's a browser setting, i.e. I have exactly zero control over it. (If I *had* any control over it, we wouldn't be having this discussion.)